# Objective-C Xcode 8.2.1 Compile Error - Class - NSLog

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to compile this code in Xcode 8.2.1. It's a very simple class, but it doesn't compile.

The code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction: NSObject

- (void) print;
- (void) setNumerator: (int) n;
- (void) setDenominator: (int) d;

@end

@implementation Fraction
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

- (void) print
{
    NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator); // <--- possible problem here?

}

- (void) setNumerator: (int) n
{
    numerator = n;
}

- (void) setDenominator: (int) d
{
    denominator = d;
}

@end

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Fraction *myFraction;

        myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
        myFraction = [myFraction init];

        [myFraction setNumerator: 1];
        [myFraction setDenominator: 3];

        NSLog (@"The value of myFraction is:");
        [myFraction print]; // <---- possible problem here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
2017-02-08 17:13:00.789 prog3point2[8643:13648415] The value of myFraction is:
(lldb)

```
libdyld.dylib`start:
    0x7fff9f7125ac <+0>: nop    
    0x7fff9f7125ad <+1>: movl   %eax, %edi
    0x7fff9f7125af <+3>: callq  0x7fff9f7125e0            ; symbol stub for: exit
    0x7fff9f7125b4 <+8>: hlt
```

Many thanks in advance, appreciate any guidance here.

Comment: Is this in your main.m file? What device or simulator are you building onto? On a side note is there a reason why you don't want to use the ViewController that is created by default and initialise your fraction object in there?

Comment: Hi @JingJingTao thanks for your reply! I'm not building onto anything, just trying to learn Obj-C. Yes, it's the main.m file. I started a new file, it's a command line tool project.

Comment: Strange I tried the exact same code as you and it works for me, can you share this project on github or something? My output, 2017-02-09 08:52:54.830 commandLineProject[38619:1484697] The value of myFraction is:
2017-02-09 08:52:54.830 commandLineProject[38619:1484697] 1/3
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: @JingJingTao thanks for trying it, glad to know the code actually compiles for you. I'll try out a few things to figure out why it doesn't work for me. Appreciate your help and time!